Getting a "'0x0A' is invalid within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. Path: $.message | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 19."
I have this json data:
{
   "guid": "73895342-7822-4871-b46c-0b345d89a3ac",
   "message": "Hhhjj
        <div style=\"background-color:#000000;border-radius:20px;webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;padding:0;margin:0;\"><iframe style=\"padding:0;margin:0;border-radius:10px;width:100%;height:200px;\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/75fDo2yk6RM\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        Vbbbbf

        <div style=\"background-color:#000000;border-radius:20px;webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;padding:0;margin:0;\"><iframe style=\"padding:0;margin:0;border-radius:10px;width:100%;height:200px;\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/75fDo2yk6RM\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>",
   "messagePlain": "Hhhjj
        https://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf
        Vbbbbf

        https://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf",
   "messageId": 0,
   "messageUpdateId": 1444
}

I have added the escape character but still get this error:
"'0x0A' is invalid within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. Path: $.message | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 19."

can someone see what I am missing?
i have this funtion:
String.prototype.escapeSpecialChars = function() {
    return this.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
               .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
               .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
               .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
               .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
               .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
               .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
               .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
};

var data ={
            guid: route.params.id,
            messageId: route.params.messageId,
            userId: userId,
            message: commentText.escapeSpecialChars(),
            messagePlain: commentPlainText.escapeSpecialChars()
        };

   fetch(endpointUrlValue + 'api/Home/PostMessage', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }})

update:

<WebView 
                        style={{flex:1,
                            marginTop:10,
                            width: '100%',
                            height: '100%',
                            fontSize:46,
                        }}
                        onMessage={(event) => {
                
                            
                            editorOnChange(event.nativeEvent.data);
                          }}
                        
                        source={{
                                html: `
                                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                                        <html>
                                            <head>
                                                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
                                                
                                            </head>
                                            <body>
                                            <style>
                                                    [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
                                                        content: attr(data-text);
                                                        cursor: text;
                                                        color: red;
                                                        pointer-events:none;
                                                    }
                
                                                    #placeholder{
                                                        position:absolute;
                                                        
                                                        color:#BDBDBD;font-size:46px;outline:none;
                                                    }
                                                    #contentHtml{
                                                        height:100%;
                                                        font-size:38px;
                                                        word-wrap: break-word;
                                                        font-family: 'Roboto';
                                                        padding:8px;
                                                        outline:none;
                                                        border:none;
                                                    }
                                                </style>
                                                <textarea id="contentHtml" rows="20"  placeholder="Enter Comment...">${commentPlainText}</textarea>
                                                
                                                
                                            </body>
                                        </html>
                                        <script>
                                        
                                            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                                                
                                                $("#contentHtml").val();
                                                $("#contentHtml").focus();
                                                $("#contentHtml").width($(document).width() - 40);
                                                $("#contentHtml").height($("#contentHtml").height() - 80 + 40);
                                                // $("#placeholder").on("click", function(){
                                                //      $("#contentHtml").focus();
                                                //      $(this).hide();
                                                // })        
                                                
                                                $("#contentHtml").on("keyup", function(e){
                                                    var contentValue = $(this).val();
                                                    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(contentValue);
                                                    // if($(this).val().trim().length === 0){
                                                    //     //alert("1 " + $(this).val().length);
                                                    //      $("#placeholder").show();
                                                    //      $("#contentHtml").focus();
                                                    // } else {
                                                    //     //alert("2 " + $(this).val().length);
                                                    //      $("#placeholder").hide();
                                                    // }
                                                });
                                            });
                                            
                                        </script>
                                        `,
                            }}>
                
                
                
                        </WebView>



const [commentText, setCommentText] = useState('');
const [commentPlainText, setCommentPlainText] = useState('');

const editorOnChange = (txt) => {
    if(route.params.isEdit){
        console.log(route.params.id);
        console.log(route.params.messageId);
        console.log(route.params.messageEditId);
        console.log(txt);
        console.log(convertLinks(txt));
        varCommentPlainText = txt;
        varCommentText = convertLinks(txt)
    }else{
        setCommentPlainText(txt);
        setCommentText(convertLinks(txt));
    }
    //setCommentPlainText(txt);
    //convertLinks(txt);
    //console.log(convertLinks(txt));
    //setCommentText(convertLinks(txt));
  }

Update:

String.prototype.escapeSpecialChars = function() {
    return this.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")
               .replace(/\\'/g, "\'")
               .replace(/\\"/g, '\"')
               .replace(/\\&/g, "\&")
               .replace(/\\r/g, "\r")
               .replace(/\\t/g, "\t")
               .replace(/\\b/g, "\b")
               .replace(/\\f/g, "\f");
};

var data ={
            guid: route.params.id,
            messageId: route.params.messageId,
            userId: userId,
            message: commentText.escapeSpecialChars(),
            messagePlain: commentPlainText.escapeSpecialChars()
        };


        console.log("JSON.parse: " + JSON.stringify(data));

JSON.parse: {"guid":"73895342-7822-4871-b46c-0b345d89a3ac","messageId":0,"userId":"9df46c98-8847-47cd-bcc2-4e0fbea254c0","message":"Hhhhjhjjj\n\n<div style=\"background-color:#000000;border-radius:20px;webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;padding:0;margin:0;\"><iframe style=\"padding:0;margin:0;border-radius:10px;width:100%;height:200px;\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/75fDo2yk6RM\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>\n\nHhhjjjj\n\n<div style=\"background-color:#000000;border-radius:20px;webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;padding:0;margin:0;\"><iframe style=\"padding:0;margin:0;border-radius:10px;width:100%;height:200px;\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/75fDo2yk6RM\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>","messagePlain":"Hhhhjhjjj\n\nhttps://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf\n\nHhhjjjj\n\nhttps://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf"}


        console.log("commentText: " + commentText);
        console.log("commentPlainText: " + commentPlainText);

commentText: Hhhhjhjjj

<div style="background-color:#000000;border-radius:20px;webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;padding:0;margin:0;"><iframe style="padding:0;margin:0;border-radius:10px;width:100%;height:200px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/75fDo2yk6RM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

Hhhjjjj

<div style="background-color:#000000;border-radius:20px;webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;padding:0;margin:0;"><iframe style="padding:0;margin:0;border-radius:10px;width:100%;height:200px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/75fDo2yk6RM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

 commentPlainText: Hhhhjhjjj

 https://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf

 Hhhjjjj

 https://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf

i event tried:
    return this.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")

and still errors

why are there newlines in those strings instead of \n? Regular strings don't support newlines...

I have updated the question to show how i am dealing with the values coming back

so how would i deal with the \n newlines when implementing the code this way

0x0A is literally those new line characters IN the JSON you would need to escape on the server side (encode them)

Use a proper JSON library when creating the JSON.

replace(/\\n/g, "\\n") should be replace(/\n/g, "\\n"). You're matching a literal \n rather than a newline, and replacing it with the same thing.

i tried you method @Barmar but still getting JSON Parse error: Unexpected end of input. i Have updated the question

Why are you escaping anything? JSON.stringify() does all the necessary escaping.

There's no way that JSON.stringify(data) will create the JSON you show. It will not put newlines in the strings, and you don't need to escape anything to remove them.

I passed this way: console.log("JSON.parse: " + JSON.stringify(data)); and shows the json result like in the update

im confused i have tried may ways still i get the error when passing into fetch

Do you start with the exact data you're showing in your first block (the JSON that isn't valid JSON because of newlines), or do you get data "from somewhere" and then you do things to it and you end up with that first code block? Because if the former: just manually make it real JSON, and if it's the latter, please show the valid JSON you're starting with.  (Also, please remember to properly indent the code you're showing, but even more importantly: please show the [mcve] for this problem so others can see exactly what's going wrong when they run your example)
